# Why am I receiving Error 1004 when trying to specify the loop variable in a cell reference?

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck, primarily because I am still brand spanking new at VBA. As such, I really appreciate any help you can lend me. I have looked through many other Error 1004 posts on here, but they were either for different issues, or it is quite possible that I am just too ignorant to know what to do with the advice in them.

My issue is this:  I have two workbooks, one with raw data, and one in which the raw data is consolidated into relevant statistics. I am trying to sumif the data in X:X in my raw workbook (6620) by two criteria in the statistics book and then update the value in the corresponding cell in the statistics book.

I am running into a Run-time Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error at the indicated points. I am lost as to how to move past this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is as far as I have gotten:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportFTEs()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim ws As Integer

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\6620\FY19*.xlsb"
        For ws = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            Sheets(ws).Name = "Sheet1"
        Next ws

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        Dim l As Integer
        Dim totalFTE As Long
        Dim lastRow As Integer
            lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim wb As Worksheet
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\FY19*.xlsb").Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim wc As Worksheet
            Set wc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B")
        Dim sum1R As Range
            Set sum1R = wb.Range("X:X")
        Dim arg2R As Range
            Set arg2R = wb.Range("D:D")
        Dim arg2C As Range
            Set arg2C = wc.Cells(7, i)
                                 >>> Error 1004
        Dim arg3R As Range
            Set arg3R = wb.Range("S:S")
        Dim arg3C As Range
            Set arg3C = wc.Cells(j, 6)
                                 >>> Error 1004
            For k = 8 To 18
                For l = 7 To 18
                    For i = 7 To 18
                        For j = 8 To 18
                            wc.Cells(k, l).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(sum1R, arg2R, arg2C, arg3R, arg3C)
                        Next j
                    Next i
                Next l
            Next k
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `i` and `j` are equal to 0 on both of those lines - what is your intent?

Comment: Also, what is that first `ws` loop doing? It looks like you're attempting to name every worksheet in your workbook "Sheet1"? What is the purpose of `lastrow` here? Too many questions, not enough clarification...

Comment: @dwirony, my intent was to shift the criteria down and across for the SUMIFS function with each loop.

And yes, the raw data workbook will only ever have one sheet, but it will have a random name. So I was trying to rename so I can then reference it.

Comment: Those `Set` lines need to be within your loops, if that is your intent. Otherwise you're setting them once and never returning to them. You should try stepping through your code line by line using F8 and you'll see what I mean :)

Comment: Turns out I have no idea what I am looking for when stepping through it. It appears to be working until I try to move through "Set arg2C = wc.Cells(7, i)".

Comment: Regarding `Set`, so it should look something like

Edit: That does not format like I thought it would...

`...
                    For i = 7 To 18
                        Set arg2C = wc.Cells(7, i)
                            For j = 8 To 18
                                Set arg3C = wc.Cells(j, 6)
                                ...
`

Comment: Not quite - one moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like this - you need the `Set` lines containing `i` and `j` *inside* their respective loops - that way the values actually increment (and aren't 0 when they're initialized):

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportFTEs()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\6620\FY19*.xlsb"

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long
    Dim totalFTE As Long

    Dim wb As Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\FY19*.xlsb").Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim wc As Worksheet
    Set wc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B")

    Dim sum1R As Range
    Set sum1R = wb.Range("X:X")

    Dim arg2R As Range
    Set arg2R = wb.Range("D:D")

    Dim arg3R As Range
    Set arg3R = wb.Range("S:S")

    Dim arg2C As Range
    Dim arg3C As Range

    For k = 8 To 18
        For l = 7 To 18
            For i = 7 To 18

                Set arg2C = wc.Cells(7, i)

                For j = 8 To 18

                    Set arg3C = wc.Cells(j, 6)

                    wc.Cells(k, l).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(sum1R, arg2R, arg2C, arg3R, arg3C)

                Next j
            Next i
        Next l
    Next k

    ActiveWorkbook.Close True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This did the trick! No more errors!

Now I just need to figure out why all of the returned values are zero... ::sigh::

Thank you so much!